# Convert Days of week into corresponding number using lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have to write a function `day_to_number(day)` that takes the supplied global list `day_list` and returns the position of the given day in that list. I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my code.

```
day_list = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

def day_to_number(day):
    for day in day_list:
        return day_list.index(day)

print day_to_number("Saturday")
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop, just `return day_list.index(day)`?

Comment: You're shadowing the parameter `day` with the loop variable, also called `day`. Therefore it's irrelevant what the input actually is.

Comment: If you will not be doing this conversion a lot index is fine. It is a linear time operation though. You could create a dict mapping of day name to index like so `daynums = {day:i for i, day in enumerate(day_list)}`. As your question specifically mentions lists I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: That made it so simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> day_list.index("Sunday")
0
```

Just use index of